# How to install lmfit package on Python3 on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, lmfit

I try to install lmfit package on my Windows 10 computer. Because I could not install the package by typing: `pip install lmfit`I typed: python `setup.py install`.  Then it shows:

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing lmfit.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to lmfit.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to lmfit.egg-info\requires.txt
writing top-level names to lmfit.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'lmfit.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching 'README.txt'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.pyc'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'core.*'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '*~'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.pdf'
warning: no files found matching '*.dat' under directory 'tests'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'doc\_build'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pdf' found under directory 'doc'
writing manifest file 'lmfit.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
UPDATING build\lib\lmfit/_version.py
set build\lib\lmfit/_version.py to '0.9.12'
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit
copying build\lib\lmfit\confidence.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit
copying build\lib\lmfit\jsonutils.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit
copying build\lib\lmfit\lineshapes.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit
copying build\lib\lmfit\minimizer.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit
copying build\lib\lmfit\model.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit
copying build\lib\lmfit\models.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit
copying build\lib\lmfit\parameter.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit
copying build\lib\lmfit\printfuncs.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit\ui
copying build\lib\lmfit\ui\basefitter.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit\ui
copying build\lib\lmfit\ui\ipy_fitter.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit\ui
copying build\lib\lmfit\ui\__init__.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit\ui
copying build\lib\lmfit\_ampgo.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit
copying build\lib\lmfit\_version.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit
copying build\lib\lmfit\__init__.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit\confidence.py to confidence.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit\jsonutils.py to jsonutils.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit\lineshapes.py to lineshapes.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit\minimizer.py to minimizer.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit\model.py to model.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit\models.py to models.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit\parameter.py to parameter.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit\printfuncs.py to printfuncs.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit\ui\basefitter.py to basefitter.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit\ui\ipy_fitter.py to ipy_fitter.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit\ui\__init__.py to __init__.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit\_ampgo.py to _ampgo.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit\_version.py to _version.cpython-37.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\lmfit\__init__.py to __init__.cpython-37.pyc
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying lmfit.egg-info\PKG-INFO -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying lmfit.egg-info\SOURCES.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying lmfit.egg-info\dependency_links.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying lmfit.egg-info\requires.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying lmfit.egg-info\top_level.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating 'dist\lmfit-0.9.12-py3.7.egg' and adding 'build\bdist.win-amd64\egg' to it
removing 'build\bdist.win-amd64\egg' (and everything under it)
Processing lmfit-0.9.12-py3.7.egg
Removing c:\users\re090\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lmfit-0.9.12-py3.7.egg
Copying lmfit-0.9.12-py3.7.egg to c:\users\re090\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
lmfit 0.9.12 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed c:\users\re090\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lmfit-0.9.12-py3.7.egg
Processing dependencies for lmfit==0.9.12
Searching for uncertainties>=3.0
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/uncertainties/
Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/uncertainties/: unknown url type: https -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'uncertainties' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/: unknown url type: https -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or working download links found for uncertainties>=3.0
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('uncertainties>=3.0')
```

This package actually runs well in other Windows 10 computer. But I got this error message on another newer Windows 10 computer. I'm wondering if it is the system's problem, which cannot be easily solved.

Do anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, not sure what the problem is -- it should work.  The `uncertainties` dependency is spelled correctly and is available on PyPI.  It is also available on conda channels `conda-forge` and `gsecars`.  That is, either

pip install uncertainties
or
   conda install -c gsecars uncertainties
or
   conda install -c conda-forge uncertainties

should work.

But, to be clear `pip install lmfit` should also have worked.  Any idea why that did not work?

Comment: `pip install lmfit` doesn't work and shows: `pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.`...